# How to store one entity class in another in specific relation between tables?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entityset

I have these relations in my data base:
[image]

I need all authors related to my book stored in book entity class?
I was trying to resolve this by using entityset but I can't use it because there is no primary key in BookAuthors table!

Any kind of help will be great! =)

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but why not simply add a primary key to BookAuthors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL **requires** a primary key in order for it to materialize entities. And since neither Books nor Authors entities know anything about each other, I think your only option is to add a PK to BookAuthors as Pleun mentioned.

This question is very similar to yours, but note the PK on the Order_Detail table: [Problem with Linq2Sql Many-to-Many relationship & Inserting new objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432283/problem-with-linq2sql-many-to-many-relationship-inserting-new-objects)